# PL/SQL procedure issue

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

I'm new to Oracle PL/SQL and have been trying to run this code but only getting the following message - PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

```
SQL> DECLARE
v_num NUMBER:=10;
BEGIN
FOR v_num IN 1..3
LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_num);
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_num);
END;
```

Comment: Did you execute this on plsql developer tool?

Comment: Oracle SQL Plus 11g Express Edition, I've generated output to other programs successfully using the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL/Plus doesn't print output by default; you have to enable it:

```
set serveroutput on
```

Afterwards, DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE will print output as expected.

Comment: Thank you, all's well now :)

Comment: As written here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG099

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can add the line

```
set serveroutput on
```

to the file

```
$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql
```

This will cause the server output to be `on` after you login to SQL*Plus -- you won't have to type it in each time you login.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Frank Schmitt has suggested a method to connect to the pl/sql server.
 However, you can also achieve this by using dbms_output view! I found this
 useful blog that explains the required steps to activate the
 dbms_output package

[SQL Developer DBMS_OUTPUT Configuration](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2016/05/13/sql-developer-plsql/)